# print an element of a list(let's say 3 lines and 2 rows,two-dimensional list) .what i'm doing wrong? for python

Tags: python, list, printing

```
playerscoins=[[10 for i in range(2)]for j in range(3)]

def currentbalance(coins):
    print("Current balance:")
    for i in range(3):
        print("Player %i has %i coins." % i , coins[i,0])

currentbalance(playerscoins)
```

```
Current balance:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#83>", line 1, in <module>
    currentbalance(playerscoins)
  File "<pyshell#82>", line 4, in currentbalance
    print("Player %i has %i coins." % i , coins[i,0])
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong with your code:

1. You're trying to use a tuple as an index to `coins`.  Since `coins` is a list of lists, you want to do `coins[i]` to get the i-th list and then `[0]` to get the first element of that list, making the expression `coins[i][0]`.
2. You're not passing a tuple to the format string.  Since there are no parens around `i, coins[i][0]`, the second part is getting interpreted as another arg to `print` rather than as another part of the operand to `%`.

Fixing those errors would look like:

```
for i in range(3):
    print("Player %i has %i coins." % (i, coins[i][0]))
```

A less confusing way to do this (if you're on Python 3, which everyone should be IMO) is to use f-strings rather than the `%` operator:

```
for i in range(3):
    print(f"Player {i} has {coins[i][0]} coins.")
```

You could also simplify the whole problem of how to index the lists by using `enumerate` to iterate over each row of `coins`.  This also saves you from having to hard-code in the number of rows:

```
for p, row in enumerate(coins):
    print(f"Player {p} has {row[0]} coins.")
```